# C# Getting properties in a property

Tags: c#, reflection

Given the following class:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public TheModel Model { get; set; }

    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        this.Model = new TheModel();
    }

    public class TheModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which is instantiated as:

```
var svm = new SampleViewModel();
```

How do I, with reflection, list the properties within svm.Model?

Note: If I use the normal GetProperties method on svm.Model I get 14 properties, all kinds of propertyinfo fields popup and none of the properties from TheModel class.

Note 2: Ok, tried with an external code like this:

```
 var svm = new SampleViewModel();
 var props = typeof(SampleViewModel).GetProperties();
 var innerprops = svm.Model.GetType().GetProperties();
```

This seems to work, now I need to figure out why the same doesnt't work when I do it inside my framework with instances created with Activator.CreateInstance. :)

thanks, pom

Comment: if everything is public then why do you need reflection?

Comment: Is this what you after: [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx)?

Comment: Sayse: I'm writing a mocking framework, so I just need to gain access to those properties through reflection. :)

Comment: Oleksii, yes, of course, but how? See the note in original message.

Comment: typeof(SampleViewModel).GetProperties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the properties of the property Model in SampleViewModel, you need to call:

```
typeof(SampleViewModel.TheModel).GetProperties();
```

or

```
svm.Model.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = svm.Model.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties) 
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

Output

```
Name
Age
Birthdate
```

GetProperties() work correctly also for Model as you see